# How do I set the header cell for a custom formula column in a clock report?

Tags: org-mode

Suppose I have a report like this.

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :link nil :scope file :formula "$3='(random)::@1$3=string(\"fubar\")"                                                                                
#+END:
```

And for completeness, I have an org buffer like this

```
* TODO Item
  CLOCK: [2015-02-15 Sun 06:20]--[2015-02-15 Sun 08:38] =>  2:18
```

When I invoke `C-c C-x C-r`, my table comes out like this.

```
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *2:18* |826342076441804571|
|--------------+--------|
| TODO Item    | 2:18   |121432529327701366|
```

But, I think it should look like this.

```
| Headline     | Time   | fubar            |
|--------------+--------|------------------|
| *Total time* | *2:18* |826342076441804571|
|--------------+--------|------------------|
| TODO Item    | 2:18   |121432529327701366|
```

Perhaps this is a bug in org-mode, but it looks like I can't set the top most cell in the column of a custom formula.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some kind of bug. You can make it work by doing the following:

- eval the `BEGIN` line
- remove the formula from the heading, leaving just `:formula`
- leave the `TBLFM` where the formula has been copied to
- run <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> while the point is in the table to align the columns
- run <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> with point on the `CAPTION` line and the column header appears

Easy!  :-)